# How to show the text of the <li> inside the text of Select_Button?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm getting confused in this part. I have a list `li` and I would like to select one item on the list and then show the text to the `Select Button`. What the SelectButton do is to open the Select_list but then I need to select a `li` and show the text on the `Select Button`.
I don't know if I'm doing right but I have doubt. Thank you for your help.

[List_window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49lvy.png)

This is the **List_Window.js**

```
export default function List_Window(props) {

const [list, setList] = useState ( [
{ id: 1, name:'Names', image:'/image-logo.svg' }, 
{ id: 2, name:'Names', image:'/image-logo.svg' }, 
{ id: 3, name:'Names', image:'/image-logo.svg' }
])

function selectedItem(e) {
    console.log(e);
    
}

return (

    <>
    <Select_Button></Select_Button>
    
    <section className='container_blur' >

        <div className={style.container}>
            <div className={style.nav}>
                <span>Select Name</span>

                <Close_Button></Close_Button>
            </div>
            <Input_search></Input_search>

            <div className={style.coin_container}>
                <ul className={style.ul}>

                    {list.map((lists) => <div className={style.li} key={lists.id}  onClick={ () => selectedItem(lists.name)} >
                        <li ><Image src={lists.image} width={27} height={35}></Image><p>{lists.name}</p></li>
                    </div>)}


                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section></>


)
}
```

[Select_Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtmdB.png)
This is the **Select_Button.js**

```
 export default function Select_Button(props) {


    function open(){
        var open = document.querySelector('.container_blur');
        
        setTimeout(function(){
          open.style.opacity = 1;
          open.style.transition = 'opacity 0.3s ease';
          }
          ,200)
  
      setTimeout(function(){
          open.style.display ='flex';
      },10)
  
    }



return (

    <div className={style.select_container}>

        <button className={style.select_btn} onClick={open} >
            <span className="text">{props.text_li}</span>
        </button>
           

    </div>


)
}
```

Comment: Welcome ! Could you edit your question with more details ? What's the expected result and what's the one you get with this code ?

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hello, sorry if it's not understandable. Well, I have the Select_Button and it has a text on it. When you click on this Button it open-up the List_Selected . Now, I want to click on one <li> and I would like to see the text of the <li> in the Select_Button. Hope it's more understandable. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the button's label to the SelectButton (child) component, and use the **'li' onclick event** to modify this label :

###### [Working Stackblitz (MCVE)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-aurnm6?file=App.tsx)

---

```js
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <section>
      <ul>
        {listVal.map((value, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index} onClick={() => setButtonLabel(value)}>
              Value: {value}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </section>
    <SelectButton buttonLabel={buttonLabel} />
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I read your modification and I edit my sugestion. I belivied you have to send a data when choose the li and get the data with Props in the other component:

```
import { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react'; 

const StartingPageContent = () => {

  const [listName, setListName] = useState();

  const listVal = [
    { id: 1, name:'Names One', image:'/image-logo.svg' }, 
    { id: 2, name:'Names Two', image:'/image-logo.svg' }, 
    { id: 3, name:'Names Three', image:'/image-logo.svg' }
    ];

    useEffect((name) => {

      setListName(name);

    }, []);

  return (
    <Fragment>

      <section>
        <h1>{ listName }</h1>


        <ul>

        {

            listVal.map((value, index) => {

                return (

                    <li key={index}>

                        <figure>

                            <img src={value.image} alt={value.name} />

                            <figcaption aria-label={value.name}>
                                <p>{value.name}</p>
                            </figcaption>

                        </figure>

                        <button type="button" onClick={ () => setListName(value.name)}>Action</button>

                    </li>

                );

            })

        }

    </ul>


      </section>

    </Fragment>
   
  );
};

export default StartingPageContent;
```

Comment: Hey, thank you but I don't think is what I meant. Sorry if I'm not really clear, I added more info. Maybe it's more understandable. Thank you again